# Loading Values from JSON not updating(as observable) Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, observable, knockout-mvc

I am working in application which have feautres like add a new row,delete a new row .All the things are working fine.Like for the very first time i am loading data from the items(i have so many viewmodel bind in a single page), there all the data seems to be working as expected (whenever the values are edited , updated in my view model).But when i load the existed data for the second time, the viewmodel is not updated as expected.the view model is holding the same data even i edited the data.i think the observable is not working properly.Kindly tell where exactly i am doing the mistake.

First time :

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //Available types - which will come from serverside
    self.typeDropDown = ko.observableArray(InitialData);

    self.typeValue = ko.observable();

//Explicitly Adding new Row
    self.Inputs = ko.observableArray([new Item(self.typeDropDown[0], '', '', '')]);

    self.removeRow = function (Item) {
        self.Inputs.remove(Item);
    },
    self.addNewRow = function () {
        //push will add a new element to the container without modifying much in DOM
        self.Inputs.push(new Item(self.typeDropDown[0], '', '', ''));
    }


function Item(Type, StrData, MaxData, Back) {
    var self = this;
    self.Type = ko.observable(Type),
    self.Storage = ko.observable(StrData),
    self.MaxIOPS = ko.observable(MaxData),
    self.BackupPercentagePerMonth = ko.observable(Back)
}
```

Second Time - Loading data from Server.

Sample Input structure from server :

```
strJSON = [
   {
       Type: storageInitialData[0].Value,
       Str: '12',
       Max: '156',
       Back: '123'
   },
    {
       Type: storageInitialData[0].Value,
       Str: '12',
       Max: '156',
       Back: '123'
   }, {
       Type: storageInitialData[0].Value,
       Str: '12',
       Max: '156',
       Back: '123'
   }
];


function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //Available types - which will come from serverside
    self.typeDropDown = ko.observableArray(InitialData);

    self.typeValue = ko.observable();

//Explicitly Adding new Row
    self.Inputs = ko.observableArray(strJSON);

    self.removeRow = function (Item) {
        self.Inputs.remove(Item);
    },
    self.addNewRow = function () {
        //push will add a new element to the container without modifying much in DOM
        self.Inputs.push(new Item(self.typeDropDown[0], '', '', ''));
    }
```

Is ko.observableArray(strJSON) is not enough to set observable property for the elements in array? Do i need to call the Item method again?

**Update**

my dropdown goes like this

```
<select class="ddText" id="selType" style="width: 100px"
                            data-bind="options:typeDropDown, optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'Value',value : (Type.Value)?Type.Value : Type,attr: { name: 'str',id : 'strType_'+$index()}, uniqueName:true" ">
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items in an `observableArray` don't themselves automatically become observable. You'll have to map your objects into `Item`s before adding them to `Inputs`. `ko.utils.ArrayMap` (or the built-in `map` method of arrays if you can be sure you're running in an ES5 browser) will be helpful here. You might also want to look into the `ko.mapping` plugin (which is officially supported); in your case it would generate the equivalent of mapping the entries to `Item`s.

Comment: Thanks this worked.but, when i resend data textboxe values are updated properly but the dropdown values are not updated .This is how i am updating the dropdown value  value : (Hyper.Value)?Hyper.Value : Hyper.am i doing it right,or for the value i need to write one custom sunction like value : selectedvalue.

Comment: Update your question to show the code you're using now.

Comment: None of the objects in your VM have a property called `value`.

Comment: let me tell you my scenario : i have dropdown type , which holds Id and Value. by default it shows the first value when i load the data from JSON that time also it is selecting the first item as a default one. whin i used the above code bindings are fine but values are not getting updated for the second time(while getting data from server).Without using (Hyper.Value) if i put hyper the alone the values are getting updated , but while setting the value it is still selecting the first one as default not the one which i selected(coming from JSON)